# How to make matlab only read dates in one year when the files consist of several year?

Tags: matlab

So, I have four excel files with dates, that I read out and convert.

`num = xlsread('1.xlsx', 1, 'A:B')`

```
num2 = xlsread('2.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
num3 = xlsread('3.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
num4 = xlsread('4.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');

dnum = datetime(num(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num(:,2));
dnum2= datetime(num2(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num2(:,2));
dnum3= datetime(num3(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num3(:,2));
dnum4=datetime(num4(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num4(:,2));



plot(dnum, 1*ones(size(dnum)), 'x-','linewidth', 1)   
plot(dnum2, 2*ones(size(dnum2)), 'x-','linewidth', 1 )
plot(dnum3, 3*ones(size(dnum3)), 'x-', 'linewidth', 1)
plot(dnum4, 4*ones(size(dnum4)), 'x-', 'linewidth', 1)
```

This are the files that contain dates from many years, but if I want to just collect dates from 2016, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter array with year.

`FilterYears=year(dnum)==2016
 FilteredData=data[FilterYears]`

Hope this helps.